# How to get Ads information from Bing Web Search API?

Tags: ads, bing-api

When I go through Bing Search API. I find that:

> "Get web, image, news, & videos results for a given query."

However, I want to get some Ads information of keywords.
For example, after searching keyword "credit card" in bing.com, I can get the ads on the right, top, bottom of the page.
So, can I  get Ads information from Bing Web Search API?

Answer (score 0):

Bing Web Search API doesn't provide Ads. It is meant for ads-free experience. For getting Bing Ads, you can try Bing Ads API: https://advertise.bingads.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/bing-partner-program/become-an-api-developer.